# Determine database permissions for database users with valid server logins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I'm looking to find a script that will provide me with the details of what permissions our current SQL server logins have. I am able to script out the current permissions of our database users. The issue I have is that a lot of the database users no longer have a corresponding SQL server login due to a variety of reasons such as domain migrations & staff leaving the company.

The script used to get the database user permissions is : <credit to Nag Pal MCTS/MCITP (SQL Server 2005/2008) this was taken from the old MSDN forum>

```sql
DECLARE @DBuser_sql VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DBuser_table TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(200), UserName VARCHAR(250), LoginType VARCHAR(500), AssociatedRole VARCHAR(200))
SET @DBuser_sql='SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,a.name AS Name,a.type_desc AS LoginType,USER_NAME(b.role_principal_id) AS AssociatedRole FROM ?.sys.database_principals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id=b.member_principal_id
WHERE a.sid NOT IN (0x01,0x00) AND a.sid IS NOT NULL AND a.type NOT IN (''C'') AND a.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND a.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY Name'
INSERT @DBuser_table
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@dbuser_sql
SELECT * FROM @DBuser_table ORDER BY DBName
```

Thank you

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: [MS q&a dup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/164306/determine-database-permissions-for-database-users.html)